# How to go to the next random activity on android studio?

Tags: android, android-intent, random, android-studio

How can I go to the next activity in random for example, on the first activity there is a button which will go to the 2nd, 3rd or 4th activity.when one of the 3 is selected how can I go to the next 2 by random? then when it is finish, it will go back again on the first activity. Please help, all I know is the "intent" and it will just go to a specific activity.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that

```
Class[] classes = new Class[3];
classes[0] = Activity0.class;
classes[1] = Activity1.class;
classes[2] = Activity2.class;
Random r = new Random();

Intent i = new Intent(this, classes[r.nextInt(classes.length)]);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i don't know how to use the shared preferences on the intent to know if the activity has been visited. can you teach me?

Comment: @MP123 you can use http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html and store the activity class name by calling this.getClass().getName()

Answer (score 1):

You can store references to your activities in a Set or Array stored in SharedPreferences for consistency.
And then, as in **letz** answer just use simple Random to get random activities.

You may also want to pop values from array to prevent duplicate intents and return back to the first activity once your array is empty.